# Outlook not receiving e-mails from php script

Tags: php, email, outlook, phpmailer, live

Okay, I'm at my whit's end here. I have a client whose site is hosted on GoDaddy and that uses Outlook. I've written a PHP script to send mail to one of their domain e-mail addresses from a contact form on their website.

I can get this e-mail to send to every single service except outlook/exchange/live/microsoft accounts.

I read that using PHPMailer was a good idea, so this is what I'm currently using to send mail:

```
//$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;                      
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                   
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";                  
$mail->Host       = "a2plcpnl0287.prod.iad2.secureserver.net";       
$mail->Port       = 465;                    
$mail->Username   = "test@alamohomefinance.com";    
$mail->Password   = "xxxxxxx";          
$mail->SetFrom('yourname@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');
$mail->AddReplyTo("name@yourdomain.com","First Last");
$mail->Subject    = "PHPMailer Test Subject via smtp (hotmail), basic";
$mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; 
$mail->MsgHTML($body);

$address = "jakerevans2@live.com"; 

if(!$mail->Send()) {
    error_log("Error from calculator!". $mail->ErrorInfo); 
} else {
 error_log("Success from calculator!");
}
```

This e-mail gets sent to my gmail account and some others, but not to my .live account or my client's Outlook address.

I've tried everything I've found on the internet so far, nothing is working. Any ideas or thoughts anyone?

Thanks!

EDIT:
The Godaddy server has an SPF record that reads:    v=spf1 include:spf.protection.outlook.com -all

I've created a DKIM key from https://www.port25.com/dkim-wizard/ and added a DKIM TXT record to GoDaddy, with the following details:

Host: key1._domainkey.alamohomefinance.com
TXT Value: k=rsa\; p=MIIBIjA...

I've added a DKIM record, with the following details:
Name: _dmarc.alamohomefinance.com
TXT Value: v=DMARC1; p=quarantine; sp=none; ruf=mailto:user@example.com; rf=afrf; pct=100; ri=86400

Am testing now to see if these changes make a difference...

Comment: spam filters at many possible locations -  would be my guess

Comment: Since it's going to some accounts and not others, the problem isn't with your script. If it had a problem it wouldn't send anywhere. So it's being filtered by the destination sites.

Comment: Yeah, my script works, just doesn't even end up in the junk folder of my jakerevans2@live.com account

Comment: You're not signing with DKIM, so that won't help. Get the basics right first!

Comment: The GoDaddy server does not have an SPF record at all, and nor does it need one because it's outbound-only.

Comment: @synchro, It has an SPF record, it had one by default, the one I placed in my original question. I found something somewhere saying to make sure it was a dash and not a tilde in front of the 'all' part, so I went to check and there it was. Also I've read that this may help outlook not view the received e-mail as spam, if the smtp host that sent it has an SPF record. Course it's not working so far.

Comment: And what about setting `SMTPDebug = 2` so you can see what it's doing? You're still apparently trying to talk SMTP to a POP3 server - I tested it, it's running Dovecot, definitely will not work with PHPMailer. You need to stop doing random things and deal with this logically!

Answer (score 0):

First up, you should look at [the PHPMailer troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting), which has a little section on GoDaddy, and many other problems.

You will get much better feedback on what's going on if you enable debug output of server messages, so set `SMTPDebug = 2`, and see what it says.

GoDaddy is known to block outbound SMTP, and generally will either simply fail to connect (see many questions on SO about that), or cause TLS verification failures as you get redirected transparently to their mail servers.

In your code you've got the `smtp.live.com` Host, but this username:

```
$mail->Username   = "a2plcpnl0287.prod.iad2.secureserver.net"
```

`secureserver.net` is the domain used for GoDaddy's mail servers, and that user name is the name of an actual GoDaddy mail server, so it seems very unlikely that you should be using it as a user id for live.com, especially since GoDaddy will be rotating mail servers frequently, so you're unlikely to get the same one every time - is that *really* your login ID for live.com?

I'm also suspicious of the phrasing of your question: you do not need to connect to live.com to send email to live.com - there's nothing stopping you sending to a live.com address from a connection through gmail, so it sounds like you may have a conceptual issue. The `Host`, `Username` and `Password` properties are for the mail server that you send out *through*, not that you are sending mail *to*.

As I said, normally GoDaddy doesn't allow remote SMTP at all, so I'm very surprised if you've had it working without using a GoDaddy mail server, so I suspect you've had something else work, not what you think.

I can also see you've based your code on an obsolete example, so make sure you're running the latest PHPMailer.

## Update:

I noticed something critical. The code does not call `$mail->isSMTP();`. This means that it's not using SMTP at all, it's using the default `mail()` function, and as such *none of the SMTP config makes any difference at all*. The message will be submitted to your local mail server, which will then relay through GoDaddy's server. Look in your mail server's log file to see what's happening, usually in `/var/log/mail.log` or similar.

Comment: but ... he said it sends fine, its just particular accounts that dont get the email. so none of the above is actually relevant

Comment: right @nogad, the issue sin't that I can't get e-mail out, which I can, either using godaddy's server (a2plcpnl0287.prod.iad2.secureserver.net) or a different one (in this case, smpt.live.com). I just can't get mail to end up in my .live inbox, nor my client's outlook inbox. They show up in gmail and others just fine.

Comment: But your code as originally posted makes no sense - you're still using a GoDaddy host name (an incorrect one at that) as a user id for live.com. Not going to work...

Comment: @Synchro, I edited the code to what I'm currently using... I copied/pasted a not great example. But, using the code above, we're back to original problem, the e-mails get sent, and arrive everywhere except .live/outlook/exchange inboxes.

Comment: Port 995?? That's the port for inbound encrypted POP3?! If your'e using `ssl`, I'd expect it to use port 465. Also, set `SMTPDebug = 2` like I said, then you'll see what's going on.

Comment: @synchro, Thanks for that catch, glanced at the wrong GoDaddy config section. still sent though using 995. huh. setting the debug will tell me what's going on where, in the e-mail server logs? I'll have to ask godaddy for access to those if that's where those are.

Comment: No, see my update - it's not using any of the SMTP config, so Port, Host, Username and Password, SMTPDebug, SMTPSecure & SMTPAuth properties are never used at all - you could just delete them!

Answer (score 0):

Check your server ip on http://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx . I've noticed Microsoft is very picky about blacklisting. I've had this issue with a brand new I.P addresses that were acquired with an apparent bad rep. If your on godaddy on a shared account ip it's very likely either the ip or entire subnets are blocked by default.